# ASP.Net DataList problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have declaratively created a LinqDataSource and DataList and bound them in markup. I have created an ItemTemplate and Edit Template.

I have bound the DataLists oneditcommand and oncancelcommand to methods in the code behind.

```
<asp:DataList ID="MyDataList" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
    Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False"
    Font-Underline="False" HorizontalAlign="Center" RepeatColumns="4" 
    oneditcommand="MyDataList_EditCommand" 
    oncancelcommand="MyDataList_CancelCommand" 
    >

<ItemTemplate>
    <div style="margin: 5px;">
        <asp:LinkButton Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" style="float:right" runat="server" />
    // Other markup    
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

When I click the LinkButton in the ItemTemplate, it runs the following code:

```
protected void DataList_EditCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            MyDataList.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
            MyDataList.DataBind();
        }
```

This works fine and puts the selected item in the DataList into edit mode. 
The Edit Template:

```
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <div style="margin: 5px;">
            <asp:LinkButton Text="Cancel" style="float:right" 
                runat="server" CommandName="cancel" CausesValidation="false"/>
      //other markup
        </div>
    </EditItemTemplate>
```

When I click the cancel button in the edit template, It does not fire the method in the code behind (the breakpoint doesn't get hit).

The Code that should be run when cancelling never get's run, so I can not exit the edit mode back into normal read mode:

```
protected void MyDataList_CancelCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        PhotoDataList.EditItemIndex = -1;
        PhotoDataList.DataBind();
    }
```

Can anyone think of a reason for this?

---- UPDATE

It seems that it is just the second firing of an event on the DataList that doesn't work, as I have know bound to the ItemCommand event, and was going to intercept the DataListCommandEventArgs.CommandName property and do something based on that. If you click the Edit link button, the ItemCommand method fires (with no code body at all), but the second time you click the edit link button, the ItemCommand method does not get hit.

Comment: Hi Ben - any chance that slapping Fiddler on the browser will shed any light on what's going on here?

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML being generated after the first command is fired?  Are the command attributes in the <asp:DataList> tag still there?

Answer (score 1):

The  name of your DataList is : "MyDataList"

but Cancel event calls PhotoDataList!

```
protected void MyDataList_CancelCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        PhotoDataList.EditItemIndex = -1;
        PhotoDataList.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't duplicate your problem, I ran this demo code and all events and templates worked fine:

[How to: Allow Users to Edit Items in DataList Web Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90xwe9s3%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Do you have any errors in your event logs? Also, I don't see the DataKeyField defined, how are you selecting your data?